# Identifying / generating a waveform?

Tags: c++, c, analysis, signals, waveform

I would like to code something that could take some sort of input and identify it as a square wave, triangle wave, or some sort of waveform. I also need some way of generating said waves.

I do have experience with C/C++, however, I'm not sure how I would approach simulating all of this. Eventually, I would like to translate it to a microcontroller program for reading its analog input to determine the waveform.

EDIT: Sorry; I should have mentioned it would be at a known frequency and the amplitude should be unknown.

Comment: Is the waveform noisy?  Do you know the frequency?  Do you know the amplitude?  In general, this is a hard problem.

Comment: Check out this free book [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm)

Comment: Sorry; I should have mentioned it would be at a known frequency and the amplitude should be unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating the waves is significantly easier than identifying them. I have a small project that does some wave generation. Here's an example from [my project](https://bitbucket.org/alexames/la/src/9139f6d54253/src/la/la_priv.cpp):

```
    float amplitude;
    switch (sound->wavetype)
    {
        case LA_SQUARE:
            amplitude = sound->theta > .5 ? 1.0 : -1.0;
            break;
        case LA_SINE:
            amplitude = sin(2 * PI * sound->theta);
            break;
        case LA_TRIANGLE:
            amplitude = sound->theta > .5 ? 4 * sound->theta - 3 : -4 * sound->theta + 1;
            break;
        case LA_SAWTOOTH:
            amplitude = 2 * sound->theta - 1.0;
            break;
        case LA_NOISE:
            amplitude = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);
            break;
        default:
            ;
    }
```

`theta` here is updated at every frame along the wave form and is dependent on the frequency of the wave you're creating.

As for identifying waves, if you know you're just going to be getting simple, unmixed square, triangle or sine waves, you can probably just do some simple tests. Look at the change in amplitude at any two points along the wave. If they're the same, square wave. If they're changing linearly (that is, if the change in amplitude is constant) you've got a triangle wave (or a sawtooth, if you're making that distinction). Otherwise, it's a sine wave. Keep in mind this check only works if you're expecting just those types of wave, and they're not being mixed or anything. There's some other edge cases in there I can think of but I'll let you worry about that.

If you're doing anything fancier, you're going to need to probably look up a book that specializes in this sort of thing, like the one suggested in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Start with MATLAB or the free GNU Octave work-alike. You can generate arrays with the desired waveforms and write appropriate functions to decode/identify. When you have the details worked out, grab a copy of the FFTW (fastest fourier transforn in the west) library to handle the fft/ifft routines for your c/c++ code. The signal processing workbench module of MATLAB has lots of useful tools to achieve your objective.

Comment: This doesn't address the real problem, which is classification of waveforms.

Comment: In the frequency domain, the couple different waveforms mentioned should be pretty distinctive.

Answer (score 0):

To identifying waveforms: If you know the frequency, you can do quite a lot by using discrete gradients, as Alex suggests in his answer.

Another method would be to use an interpolation technique and have a look at the coefficients. Still another would be a fast Fourier transform. These last two are computationally more intense, but also much more accurate, especially when identifying more complex waveforms. You would have to see whether your uC is fast enough or, if you are lucky, has a hardware-FFT.